# Unit testing PHP that calls filesystem functions

Tags: php, unit-testing, filesystems

I want to test a new method in a helper class with phpUnit.

```
public function removeDuplicateLines() {
    $lines = file($this->getFilePath());
    $lines = array_unique($lines);
    file_put_contents($this->getFilePath(), implode($lines));
}
```

Is it possible to test a method that calls file() and file_put_contents(), without creating a file in the test case itself? Is there a recommended way to test the above method in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test if your code is working, then perhaps you should let the code do what it is expected to.

If you really don't want to mess around with files, then just use a stream in your class (which will have a performance / capacity impact in production. PHPunit [can do most of this](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#test-doubles.mocking-the-filesystem) for you.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to PHP7, I used [vfsStream](http://vfs.bovigo.org/) for all my tests against the filesystem; but I haven't tried using it with PHP7 yet, so can't confirm that it supports that version of PHP (although there's no reason why it shouldn't)